# Is there a way to rename a discovery after you upload it?

Tags: no-mans-sky

After a couple of hours exploring, I discovered a few Star Systems and a multitude of planets. I uploaded a lot of the data, but I had forgotten to rename my discoveries before I uploaded all of my data.

I know how to rename *before* uploading data, but is there a way to rename *after* uploading data?

Comment: Pretty sure the answer is no but it's hard to prove a negative. This drove me a little nuts after I uploaded a typo.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was able to go back to the previous save after making a typo and rename and upload an animal again.

Comment: Won't it use the first name someone gives it when showing the data to other players, though?